# Скриншот всех элементов контрола на Windows Forms, в том числе за границей видимости

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls, scrollbar

В моей программе нужно реализовать возможность скриншота всех элементов, находящихся внутри панели. Главная проблема в том, что нужно также скриншотить элементы, которые могут не уместиться на этой панели (появляются scrollBar'ы).
Написал пока такой метод

```
private Bitmap DrawPanelToBitmap()
{
    //Определяю границы
    int hmax = 6, wmax = 6;
    foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
    {
        int w = item.Width + item.Left + 6;
        int h = item.Height + item.Top + 6;
        if (wmax < w) wmax = w;
        if (hmax < h) hmax = h;
    }
    int hmin = hmax - 6, wmin = wmax - 6;
    foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
    {
        int h = item.Top - 3;
        int w = item.Left - 3;
        if (wmin > w) wmin = w;
        if (hmin > h) hmin = h;
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wmax - wmin, hmax - hmin);
    Rectangle rectangle = panel1.RectangleToScreen(panel1.ClientRectangle);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(rectangle.Location, Point.Empty, bitmap.Size);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Результат отобразил на новой форме - в начале идет сама панель со всеми дочерними контролами, затем идет остальная часть формы и даже то, что находится за ней. 
[image: результат]
Нужно, чтобы не было видно того, что находится за границей панели. На ум приходит прокрутка по всей области и склейка всех этих участков, но не хотелось бы, чтобы пользователю была видна вся эта абракадабра.

Интересно узнать ваши советы по этому поводу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод скриншотит любой отдельный контрол или форму(она тоже является контролом). Даже если часть контрола скрыта.

**Работает оптимальнее чем перебор скриншотов всех контролов** и меньше нагружает компьютер.

НО! на медленных машинах может не заскриншотить форму. С остальными контролами скриншотит как нужно всегда

```
    public Bitmap GetControlScreenshot(Control control)
    {
        //ресайзим контрол до возможного максимума перед скриншотом
        Size szCurrent = control.Size;
        control.AutoSize = true;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);//создаем картинку нужных размеров
        control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, control.ClientRectangle);//копируем изображение нужного контрола в bmp

        //возвращаем размер контрола назад
        control.AutoSize = false;
        control.Size = szCurrent;

        return bmp;
    }
```

Так же более медленный, но более надежный способ (работает и на медленных машинах хорошо):

```
    private Bitmap GetControlScreenshot(Control control)
    {
        var size = control.DisplayRectangle.Size;

        Rectangle rect = control.DisplayRectangle;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

        //Black background fix
        if (control is Form)
        {
            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(control.BackColor))
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
            }
        }

        foreach (Control item in control.Controls)
            item.DrawToBitmap(bmp, item.Bounds);

        return bmp;
    }
```

Здесь добавлен фикс на черный бэкграунд при скриншоте с формы.

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается это куда проще, чем думал.

```
private Bitmap DrawPanelToBitmap()
{
    Rectangle rect = panel1.DisplayRectangle;
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
    foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
        item.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, item.Bounds);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Ну может кому еще пригодится