# Сохранение panel в виде картинки (windows forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Cделала простую программу по типу поинта, возникла проблема в сохранении изображения с панели, окно сохранения выскакивает, но в итоге ничего не сохраняет, в чем может быть проблема?
Так выглядит программа:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g = pnl_Draw.CreateGraphics();
    }
    bool startPaint = false;
    Graphics g;
    int? initX = null;
    int? initY = null;
    bool drawSquare = false;
    bool drawRectangle = false;
    bool drawCircle = false;

    private void pnl_Draw_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        startPaint = true;
        if (drawSquare)
        {
            // use Solid Brush for filling the graphic shapes
            SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(btn_PenColor.BackColor);
            // setting the width and height same for creating square
            // getting the width and higth value from Textbox
            g.FillRectangle(sb, e.X, e.Y, int.Parse(txt_ShapeSize.Text), int.Parse(txt_ShapeSize.Text));
            // setting startPint and drawSquare value to false for creating one graphic on one click
            startPaint = false;
            drawSquare = false;
        }
        if (drawRectangle)
        {
            SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(btn_PenColor.BackColor);
            // setting the width twic of the height
            g.FillRectangle(sb, e.X, e.Y, 2 * int.Parse(txt_ShapeSize.Text), int.Parse(txt_ShapeSize.Text));
            startPaint = false;
            drawRectangle = false;
        }
        if (drawCircle)
        {
            SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(btn_PenColor.BackColor);
            g.FillEllipse(sb, e.X, e.Y, int.Parse(txt_ShapeSize.Text), int.Parse(txt_ShapeSize.Text));
            startPaint = false;
            drawCircle = false;
        }
    }




    private void btn_kwadrat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawSquare = true;
    }

    private void btn_kolo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawCircle = true;

    }

    private void btn_prostokond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawRectangle = true;
    }

    private void pnl_Draw_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (startPaint)
        {
            Pen p = new Pen(btn_PenColor.BackColor, float.Parse(cmb_PenSize.Text));
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(initX ?? e.X, initY ?? e.Y), new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            initX = e.X;
            initY = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void btn_PenColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog color = new ColorDialog();
        if (color.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            btn_PenColor.BackColor = color.Color;
        }
    }

    private void pnl_Draw_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        startPaint = false;
        initX = null;
        initY = null;
    }

    private void btn_zapiśz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Jpeg Image|*.jpg| Bitmap Image|*bmp|Gif Image|*gif";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnl_Draw.Width, pnl_Draw.Height);
            pnl_Draw.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl_Draw.Width, pnl_Draw.Height));
            bmp.Save("panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }

            ms.Close();
        }
    }


    private void btn_odczytaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.pnl_Draw.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(fileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }

    
    private void zamknij_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Фрагмент кода с сохранением:

private void btn_zapiśz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Jpeg Image|*.jpg| Bitmap Image|*bmp|Gif Image|*gif";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnl_Draw.Width, pnl_Draw.Height);
            pnl_Draw.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl_Draw.Width, pnl_Draw.Height));
            bmp.Save("panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }

            ms.Close();
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/930788/186752

Answer (score 0):

Может быть надо не

```
bmp.Save("panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

а

```
bmp.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```