# c# DataGridView to Bitmap

Tags: c#, datagridview, bitmap

Всем привет. Нужно конвертировать таблицу в картинку. Самый очевидный, как по мне способ - каждую отдельную строку "сфотографировать", сохранить в лист и затем соединять в одну большую картинку. Написал вот такой код:

```
            List<byte[]> rowList = new List<byte[]>(); //здесь сохраняем все строки
            for (int i = 0; i < OrderDataGrid.Rows.Count; i++) //вот тут всё идеально работает и прекрасно сохраняется
            //(исключение - если таблица не влезает вся в экран, вылазит исключение. Пока что, не знаю, как с этим разобраться)
            {
                OrderDataGrid.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                Size dgvSz = OrderDataGrid.ClientSize;
                int rw = OrderDataGrid.Rows[i].Index;
                Rectangle RowRect = OrderDataGrid.GetRowDisplayRectangle(rw, true);
                using (Bitmap bmpDgv = new Bitmap(dgvSz.Width, dgvSz.Height))
                using (Bitmap bmpRow = new Bitmap(RowRect.Width, RowRect.Height))
                {
                    OrderDataGrid.DrawToBitmap(bmpDgv, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, dgvSz));
                    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmpRow))
                    {
                        G.DrawImage(bmpDgv, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, RowRect.Size), RowRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        string DesktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bmpRow.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                            rowList.Add(stream.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            int TotalHeight = (OrderDataGrid.RowCount * OrderDataGrid.RowTemplate.Height) +
                        OrderDataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight;
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(OrderDataGrid.ClientSize.Width, TotalHeight);
            result.SetResolution(100, 100);
    
            TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result);
            int btmCount = 0; //счётчик bitmap
            for (int y = 0; y < TotalHeight - OrderDataGrid.RowTemplate.Height; y += OrderDataGrid.RowTemplate.Height)
            {//вот тут происходит какая-то странная магия и всё ломается. Не могу понять, в чём дело
            //Он выдаёт мне результат, но это просто 6 пустых строк
                using (Bitmap tempBitmap = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(rowList[btmCount]))
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < OrderDataGrid.ClientSize.Width; x += 1)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(tempBitmap, x, y);
                    }
                }
                btmCount++;
            }
            string DesktopFolder2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            result.Save(Path.Combine(DesktopFolder2 + @"\Folder\", "datagridview.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
```

result:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему построчно, а не всю таблицу сразу? Зачем вы делаете `List<byte[]>`, если можно `List<Bitmap>`? Можно просто созданные битмапы не диспозить сразу, а только после того как оно стало не нужно.

Comment: Вообще нужен воспроизводимый пример. Так как тестировать показанный код нет возможности.

Comment: Такое пробовали? `using Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(OrderDataGrid.Size.Width, OrderDataGrid.Size.Height); OrderDataGrid.DrawToBitmap(bmp, dataGridView.Bounds); bmp.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: 1. (почему построчно) Таблица может быть большой и не влезать вся в экран, поэтому мне показалось проще реализовать "скан" каждой отдельной строки. 2. (битмапы не диспозить сразу) Имеете ввиду, их объединять сразу же в самом 1 цикле? 3. (3 комментарий) Да, пробовал что-то примерно подобное писать, но опять же, как писал в 1 пункте, столкнулся с проблемой, что, если datagridview слишком длинная и не влезает весь, то остатки таблицы, которые не влезли, они не вставляются в bitmap

Comment: Есть лайфхак, убираете скролл у DGV, засовываете ее в Panel, а у панели делаете скролл. В результате DGV будет всегда в полный рост, даже если не будет влезать в экран. Проблема с такой DGV может возникнуть, если строк очень-очень много, например несколько тысяч, будет притормаживать. Плюс заголовки таблицы будут скролиться вместе с таблицей, но это можно тоже обкостылить. Когда-то этот вариант, правда я его реализовывал с целью попиксельного скрола, для меня сработал. Подойдет ли вам - не знаю.

Comment: Но конечно более правильный вариант, это написать метод рендера строки самостоятельно, то есть рисовать ячейки на битмапе и текст в них програмно, а не заставляя контролы отрисовываться там. Грубо говоря, не DGV рисуете, а сами данные. Задача не тривиальная, но зато можно получить стабильный рендер битмапа своими руками.

Comment: Касаемо скроллбаров: Нужно что-то такое сделать? OrderDataGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None; OrderPanel.AutoScroll = true; Не нашёл свойство у панели, как и у dgv

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скриншот всех элементов контрола на Windows Forms, в том числе за границей видимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900905/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows-forms-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc)

Comment: Это было очень давно, я уже не вспомню, но кода там было нормально так понаписано, с учетом автоскрола при изменении выделенной ячейки. Помню только что ничего сложного там не было.

Comment: Зайду с конца. Итоговый битмап - он для чего нужен? Что потом делается с этой картинкой? Объясните нам и, возможно, окажется, что от битмапа можно полностью избавиться. Например, вы пихаете его в какой-то документ (Word) - так может лучше _данные_ передавать туда?

Comment: А, ну , если в двух словах, таблицу нужно запихнуть как-нибудь в QR-код. Решение этой проблемы - запихнуть её в картинку. Картинку загрузить на хост и в QR-коде разместить ссылку на эту картинку. Вроде, логично и просто звучит :)

Comment: Что из себя представляет хост? Сделать там html-табличку, не?

Comment: Картинкообменник простой, на который делаю post запрос через api

Comment: Хорошо, принято. | Может, лучше будет выводить данные на битмап вручную с помощью Graphics.DrawString? | Ещё как вариант могу предложить вместо картинкообменника использовать сайт наподобие pastebin - размещать там данные в виде текста, без всякой возни с картинками. А далее, как и сейчас - QR со ссылкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий способ. Работает не очень быстро и немного дёргано, но работает. Если подскажите, как его можно оптимизировать, буду благодарен. (сделал "общим")

```
    int TotalHeight = (OrderDataGrid.RowCount * OrderDataGrid.RowTemplate.Height) +
                OrderDataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight;
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(OrderDataGrid.ClientSize.Width, TotalHeight);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result);
    result.SetResolution(100, 100);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < OrderDataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        OrderDataGrid.Rows[i].Selected = true;
        Size dgvSz = OrderDataGrid.ClientSize;
        int rw = OrderDataGrid.Rows[i].Index;
        Rectangle RowRect = OrderDataGrid.GetRowDisplayRectangle(rw, true);
        using (Bitmap bmpDgv = new Bitmap(dgvSz.Width, dgvSz.Height))
        using (Bitmap bmpRow = new Bitmap(RowRect.Width, RowRect.Height))
        {
            OrderDataGrid.DrawToBitmap(bmpDgv, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, dgvSz));
            using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmpRow))
            {
                G.DrawImage(bmpDgv, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, RowRect.Size), RowRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                g.DrawImage(bmpRow, x, y);
            }
        }
        y += OrderDataGrid.RowTemplate.Height;
        try
        { OrderDataGrid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex++; }
        catch { }
    }
    string DesktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    result.Save(Path.Combine(DesktopFolder, "datagridview.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: result нужно еще освободить после окончания работы или взять в конструкцию using . Еще можно обходить не по одному row а сразу по 10. Но это сложно в 2х словах описать как под это изменить код. Попробуй сам - если не получится, создай новый вопрос. А этот отметишь решенным свой ответ через пару дней

Comment: Вам не нужно делать ответы общими. Это ни на что не влияет кроме того что их смогут редактировать новички и вы не получите за такие ответы положительной репутации.

Answer (score 1):

Найдено в гугле по первой ссылке по... ***заголовку этого вопроса***

```
//Изменить высоту к оригинальной
int height = dataGridView1.Height;
dataGridView1.Height = dataGridView1.RowCount * dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height;

//Создать битмап и врисовать туда DataGridView
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));

//Изменить DataGridView назад к оригинальному размеру
dataGridView1.Height = height;

//Сохранить в папку
bitmap.Save(@"D:\Images\DataGridView.png");
```

код взят с: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Export-DataGridView-to-Bitmap-PNG-Image-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Если-бы всё было так легко, я бы не задавал вопрос... У меня возникла проблема с тем, что у меня обрезается часть таблицы, если количество строк слишком велико

Comment: тогда печатай в картинку: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-print-a-data-grid-in-C-Sharp-and-net/ -- метод `DrawRows`

Comment: Осторожнее, мне тут за косвенные призывы погуглить, бан на сутки влепили.

Comment: @aepot отколе косвенные призывы стали банить? По каким именно правилам ресурса? Кроме того я все время которое сижу на ресурсе периодически пишу в ответах по каких кейвордах в поисковике я нашел ответ. С целью научить людей гуглить. По этому поводу даже вопрос на мете создавал: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8466/186752  | Запрета на  такие действия я не увидел в справке в т.ч. А с ответом от αλεχολυτ в том вопросе я не согласен :) Просто моя практика показала что людям которых я обучал так или иначе все равно приходится обьяснять как пользоваться поисковиком на своем примере.

Comment: @Andrew я позавчера тока из бана вылез за коммент типа "Вот ссылка1 ссылка2, но лучше убедиться что инфы в поиске нет прежде чем задавать вопрос". Хотя, у нас хотят - банят, хотят - не банят, не разберешь порой.

Comment: @aepot Забанить бы такого человека с банхаммером что бы подумал хорошенько над своим поведением. :)

Comment: Сами проголосовали - сами терпим. Пусть будет как будет.

Comment: @Andrew Обычно, я гуглю вопрос (на русском, на английском и на арабском), захожу в ютуб и делаю тоже самое и тоже самое делаю на форумах, на которых частенько сижу. Если не нахожу решение моей проблемы - пишу сюда. В данном случае, проблема была в том, что у меня "резался" скриншот по нижнему краю DGV. Ниже создал ответ на вопрос. Если не трудно, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Если я кого-то чем-то задел - прошу прощения. Я никому, вроде, не кидал жалобы и не планировал блокировать как-либо...

Comment: @Frehzy не, никого не задел. Не волнуйся. Просто хорошей практикой является указывать такие штуки как "гуглил и пробоввал то-то, а не получилось то-то" в самом вопросе. Так человек который будет оставлять ответ сможет лучше сориентироваться в проблеме и дать ответ быстрее и коректнее.

Comment: Хорошо, возьму на заметку. Спасибо всё равно за помощь с печатью картинки. Хоть меня c# и послал в далёкое и прекрасное и так же, как и обычно, обрезал таблицу, но решение всё равно нашлось

Comment: @Frehzy хорошо то, что хорошо кончается :) Удачи в начинаниях! Код просмотрю и если будут идеи по оптимизации сходу - отпишусь

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, это самый простой способ отрисовать весь DataGridView в Bitmap:

```
using (var form = new Form())
using (var dgv = new DataGridView())
{
    dgv.Parent = form;
    dgv.AutoSize = true;
    dgv.DataSource = source;

    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(dgv.Width, dgv.Height))
    {
        dgv.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, dgv.Bounds);
        bitmap.Save("datagridview.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Если задать свойство `AutoSize = true;`, то грид увеличится (или уменьшится) так, чтобы вместить все строки. После чего вызов `DrawToBitmap` даст желаемый результат.

Т. к. нежелательно, чтобы реальный контрол менял размеры на реальной форме (это может привести к пересчёту всего Layout), создаём временную форму и грид.

`source` - это источник данных (коллекция), к которому делаем привязку. Если у вас не используется Data binding, то нужно у временного грида создать такие же колонки, как у реального и скопировать в него строки.

Что интересно, эту временную форму не обязательно показывать вызовом `Show()` или `ShowDialog()`, а гриду обязательно нужно иметь родителя.